# insert image on table view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiimage

How can I insert an image on simple tableview? I have an tableview but if I insert like this:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
```

I see the image in every cell that isn't empty the start of the image, and this is horrible!

Thanks for the attention!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the **background of a TableViewController** you can use this code in the `viewDidLoad` method:

```
self.parentViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

---

If you are trying to **set an image in the cell** itself you can use this code in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
```

Comment: thanks!!!this is the solution: self.parentViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];